# Should i use cell registered or grid registered bathymetric data in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, bathymetry, habitat-modeling

I am planning on calculating habitat volume over great ocean distances and have the choice to use either Grid or cell registered data, downloadable from this link.

http://ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/global.html

Does QGIS prefer one system? I will most likely be using WGS84 coordinate system to calculate by volumes in the case this has an impact as well.